# X-Wing cockpit display function

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

Does the brightly lit centre display of the x-wing cockpit have any meaningful use to the pilot?

[image]

Comment: It looks pretty.

Comment: Warning indicator? You are flying towards something incredibly dangerous...

Comment: Distance to target - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wnaD38aIgG4

Comment: *"Meaningful Use"* Well obviously it does...otherwise they wouldn't put it there. What it actually *means*...is a **whole** different thing.

Comment: Could be a JJ Abrams lens flare detector

Comment: @Paulie_D - I don't recall any death stars in Episode 7.  Looks like a display of some kind of lines of force to me.

Comment: @ScottWhitlock - I assumed it was something to do with the shields.

Comment: I would say it is a three dimensional artificial horizon, displaying the X-Wings relative attitude from a fixed point known only by the shipboard computer, astromech droid, or pilot.

Comment: @ScottWhitlock: _"I don't recall any death stars in Episode 7"_ Watch it again.

Comment: After watching Star Wars while it was on a TBS Marathon this weekend, that same "shiny star symbol" can be seen on several terminals in the Rebel Base on Yavin as well. I am sure that it was used several times as "technological filler" and one could spot it in the original trilogy - maybe add it to the drinking game list.

Comment: Clearly the pilot has taken a photograph of a Cylon BaseStar with the flash still on..

Comment: Could it be a multimedia device? Perhaps the pilot was watching a movie during those long seconds between TIE fighters to blow up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Star Wars: Blueprints - Rebel Edition](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Blueprints:_Rebel_Edition), this is the "*Primary Display Monitor*".

[image]

The text below this panel reads;

> *The **Primary Display Monitor** is a multi-function instrument that can be
>   pre-programmed for optimised readouts, streamlining standard flight
>   information with data related to tactical conditions, reconnaissance
>   and communications.*

Comment: We see the targeting scope (22) during the Death Star trench run in Ep. IV, and in Ep. V R2-D2's comments are translated on the autopilot/astromech monitor (12) of Luke's X-wing.

Answer (score 2):

It's the armament, the targeting computer, it's just on a sleep mode of sorts.

[image: Image result for armament xwing]

Comment: Why would it be on "sleep mode" in the middle of a battle?

Comment: Just a note: you could have edited your previous answer instead of deleting it and posting a new one. You can always [edit] your own posts.

Comment: For the record, the display in the X-Wing games does many things that we know it doesn't do in the films, for example acting as the targeting computer and displaying R2's dialogue